# Find all vertex that every path visit

Tags: compiler-construction, graph-theory

I have a directed graph. With (exactly) one beginning and one end. I need to find those vertices which **every** possible path from beginning to end visit.

The slow approach would be going through every possible path and +1 every vertice I visit. All vertices which have the same total visits than the beginning (or end).. are the vertices I'm looking for.

I need to know this for an optimization in a compiler I'm writing. I want to know where all control flow paths merge.

If somebody could point me to the right name of such an algorithm, that would already help. (As my knowledge of graph theory is not very good)

Comment: Find all the nodes that dominate the exit node. Domination analysis is a well known and trivial algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominator_(graph_theory)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's the name I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I just realized it's actually very simple.
As the graph I have is already topologically sorted. I travel it (sorted), add every "branch out" to a list. On every vertex I first remove all "branch outs" that come to this vertex, if there are no more "branch outs", this vertex is visited by all path.